# How can i read message of particular user in telegram group using telegram bot i am using node-telegram-bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to read particular user  latest messages i have userId but i want to read all messages send by that user.
I want if there is any bot functions which can be used for this.
I also want to know can i read reactions on a particular message of that user

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to filter the messages by sender id. You should:

1. Disable the [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode).

> A bot running in privacy mode will not receive all messages that
> people send to the group.

2. When you have an incoming update, check for the update.message.from.id to know if he's the target user.
3. use `copyMessage` or `forwardMessage` to send his message to yourself.

Here's a simple example using PHP/[TeleBot](https://github.com/webpajooh/telebot):

```php
$tg = new TeleBot('your-token');
if ($tg->user->id == 'target-user-id') {
    $tg->forwardMessage([
        'chat_id' => 'your-user-id',
        'from_chat_id' => $tg->chat->id,
        'message_id' => $tg->message->message_id,
    ]);
}
```

---

You can also check out this repository to more know and get inspired:
https://github.com/mkleymenov/telespy-bot